# Implicitly using latest version (0.202.0) for https://deno.land/std/path/mod.ts

Tags: deno, dts

I am trying to build my project and its giving error with latest std version 0.202.0.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cc7Cd.png)
[This is my Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyyb9.png)
I have spent some time to investigate the error , but it seems to be issue with latest version. but how can i force mod.ts to pull the older version.
I have below code in my file.

```
import { Base64 } from "https://deno.land/x/bb64/mod.ts";
import { readAllSync } from "https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/io/util.ts";
import { basename } from "https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/path/mod.ts";

const version = "$Revision$";
const usage = `
DTS Command Line Tooling: importexcel

Usage:
importexcel --version
importexcel -h | --help
importexcel <DataFile>

Options:
  -h --help         Show this screen.
  --version         Show version of this command.
`;
import docopt from "https://deno.land/x/docopt@v1.0.1/dist/docopt.mjs";
import { MultipartWriter } from "https://deno.land/std@0.100.0/mime/multipart.ts";

function importexcel(args: any) {
}

const repo = "PTCSC.DataImport.UploadAndBackupRepository";
var sourcePath = "/DataImport"; // Default sourcePath

async function upload(opts: any, properties: any) {
  try {
    const dataFile = opts["<DataFile>"];
```

Not getting how to try to pull older version

Comment: How is C++ tag std related to your typescript code?

Comment: Please be kind to read the tag description.

Comment: @273K    Sorry I didn’t get , is there anything i am missing

Comment: Just click the tag and read the description and see you misuse the C++ tag.

Comment: @273K Oh sorry , removed it .

Answer (score 0):

Run `deno info` so you can see which file is importing those unpinned dependencies.

If it's one of your files that is importing them, you can just pin the version in your `import` statement.

If it's one of your dependencies that is in turn importing unpinned dependencies, you will have to either change the code in the dependency repository, or you can "embed" the dependency into your project with `deno vendor` and then edit its `import` to use fixed versions (an older version in your case). Ideally, if the dependency itself is broken, it should be fixed in the dependency itself (upstream).